# Biber not stable, sometimes running amok

Tags: biber

Since a couple of days I encounter frequent crashes with biber. While sometimes it runs flawlessly, other times it blocks the compiling with these errors: Interestingly in the last trial with latexml there was one run which finished, then a run with pdflatex and the next run with biber crashed. There was no change in the bib.file inbetween.

```
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'biber Chap10only'
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
Latex failed to resolve 36 reference(s) Latex failed to resolve 2 citation(s)
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'makeindex Chap10only.idx'
Latexmk: Run number 2 of rule 'biber Chap10only'
Can't spawn "biber --onlylog "Chap10only"": No error at f:\Texlive\2015\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl line 8423.
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
biber Chap10only: Biber errors: See file 'Chap10only.blg' Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing, unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
f:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:665: command failed with exit code 12: perl.exe f:\Texlive\2015\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -pdf -silent -latexoption=-synctex=1 Chap10only

Process exited with error(s)
```

I have controlled the library running biber from the command line and it works:

```
E:\BuchprojektSpringer\VierteAuflage>biber Chap10only
INFO - This is Biber 2.4
INFO - Logfile is 'Chap10only.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Chap10only.bcf'
INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Found 289 citekeys in bib section 1
INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 1
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Literatur/EndokrinologieKunde.bib' for section 1
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Literatur/EndokrinologieKunde.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'nyt/global' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nyt' and locale 'de-DE'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
INFO - Writing 'Chap10only.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to Chap10only.bbl
```

Comment: It would be more interesting to know the content of the Chap10only.blg after such an error.

Comment: [242] Biber.pm:741> INFO - Found 289 citekeys in bib section 1
 [243] Biber.pm:741> INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
 [261] Biber.pm:3150> INFO - Processing section 1
     [347] Biber.pm:3307> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Literatur/EndokrinologieKunde.bib' for section 1
     [1443] bibtex.pm:1124> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
     [2431] bibtex.pm:985> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Literatur/EndokrinologieKunde.bib'
     [5776] bibtex.pm:92> FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV
     Likely your .bib has a very bad entry which causes libbtparse to crash:

Comment: the command line run finesh successfully

Comment: Can you reproduce a crash from the command line at all? I once managed to get sporadic SIGSEV errors with a bad `.bib` file - it wouldn't appear all the time, but every third or fourth run it would rear its ugly head. Can you try to narrow down which entry causes the crash and post the offending entry here? Especially names can be problematic ([see my problem here](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/87)).

Comment: I have tried to see a debug option with biber. But with no success. Can you help me with that? --@moeve I have seen your problem and it looks very much the same.

Comment: @moeve: obviously the import in Jabref into the bibfile was not completely utf8, I had a couple of incorrect formatted umlaute in several name fields. These gave an unexspected error in an biber run I had not seen before: (multiple) Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected continuation byte 0xb4, with no preceding start byte) in subroutine entry at C:\Users\bk\AppData\Local\Temp\par-626b\cache-a29446bef12fcafa74d1affb0f
27cf9ac0385\inc\lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 975.
If this is the reason for errors I donot know but I hope.

Comment: Do you think you could write that down as a self-answer?

Comment: I have now biber 2.5 and biblatex 3.5 through texlive pretest. The errors are not gone.

Comment: Mhhh, interesting. I couldn't reproduce the problem with your example below. But then again the error I reported back in the day did not occur all the time, maybe I'm just lucky today. If you can reproduce the problem consistently, try to come up with an example that is as minimal as possible yet still reproduces the problem and report the issue with as much additional info (`--debug`/`--trace` logs, system info) at the Biber bugtracker.

Comment: That was at least the offending entry and changing it had an effect. I do not want much to play with it, but will try tomorrow whether it is indead the case.

Comment: I can not reproduce the error and the crash. But I have the command in texstudio for biber changed to `biber --debug %s` to be able to identify offending entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the info about `biber --debug` and it turned out the offending entry was just the one that was not created.

```
author = {D'Amato, E. and Giacopelli, F. and Giannattasio, A. and D'Annunzio...
```

Putting D'Amato and D'Annuncio in parenthesis was the solution. Actually I do not know what a `'` does to biber to crash. Whether the other non-UTF entries caused any problem I do not know.